# why Axios promises doesn't get executed in order in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, render, es6-promise

```
useEffect(() => {    
    if(reviewsData) {      
      reviewsData.forEach( item =>          
        {
          if(item)
          {            
            item.text.forEach((review,i) =>            
                {                  
                  axios({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "http://localhost:5000/retrieveuserbyid",
                    data: {
                      userId: item.user
                    },
                    headers: {
                      authToken: localStorage.getItem("authToken"),
                      "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    }
                  }).then(res => {                      
                      const name =res.data.name;                      
                      setTempUser([...tempUser , name]);                      
                      tempUser2 = [...tempUser2, name];                      
                      console.log(name);                     
                      console.log(tempUser2);     
                    }).catch(err => {                     
                    });                   
                }              
             )             
          }        
      }      
      );
    }
  }, [reviewsData]
);
```

reviewsData.text are comments people post on my site and I want to retriev username for each person leaving comments. (store them into a array initially) but I don't understand why in the state tempUser I have only the last user and in the tempUser2 I have all the users but in a random order each time I refresh. *One person can leave multiple comments.

Answer (score 0):

React state updates are asynchronous. When you queue up all the axios promises the current value of `tempUser` is enclosed and used for *all* the state updates. If you use a functional state update, however, they can be correctly queued up and processed. Functional state updates allow each queued update to access the previous update, i.e. each updated depends on the previous one.

```
then(res => {                      
  const name =res.data.name;                      
  setTempUser(tempUser => ([...tempUser , name]));                      
  tempUser2 = [...tempUser2, name];                      
  console.log(name);                     
  console.log(tempUser2);     
})
```

*Side note: Axios is capable of [concurrent](https://github.com/axios/axios#concurrency) fetches (`axios.all`), and since axios uses promises, you can also map a bunch of requests and use `Promise.all`, which returns an array of all resolved axios requests, in the order they were queued up (if order matters).*

Comment: It works by adding the callback with last value as a parameter but I have to return them in order. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Will study the axios.all as you suggested.